Can top down approach and bottom up approach to a problem have different theoretical time complexities?
I am NOT talking about the speed or time it takes in practice to compute the solution of a problem using top down or bottom up approach. By top down I mean a memoization based approach and by bottom up I mean a tabulation based approach. Will they have the same theoretical time complexity for every problem?

For a problem that can be solved using dynamic programming, a bottom-up approach has polynomial complexity (except for NP-complete problems such as knapsack, for which we get a pseudo-polynomial algorithm). However, a top-down recursive approach  has exponential complexity if not implemented using the memoization technique (in which case, the complexity is again polynomial).
EDIT: the op modified his question on September 11 2024 after I answered (on September 10), and he basically incorporated my answer into his question. Of course, this now rules out my answer. See my answer to the op in the comments.

The top-down approach is basic a divide and conquer approach corresponding to a direct, recursive implementation of the dynamic programming recurrence equation solving the problem. That divide and conquer algorithm will have exponential complexity unless you implement it using memoization, so my answer was: there is a case in which the top-down approach has a different complexity, depending on how smart you are in implementing it. Let me know what you think about, I can delete the answer in case, although I believe this may be actually useful to someone, since this is often overlooked.

@MassimoCafaro Sorry but this doesn't really answer my question.

Well, this does not asnwer your question AFTER you CHANGED your question. I answered on September 10, you modified your question on September 11 by incorporating my answer into your question. That said, the question is now ruling out my  answer of course; however you should be honest in recognizing that you did not think about what I answered when you originally posed the question.

@MassimoCafaro, Thank you for pointing that out.  I totally missed that change.  I agree; changing the question to invalidate an existing answer is not considered appropriate on Stack Exchange.

@A-ar, The general advice is to make sure when crafting your question that it asks what you really want to know, and include all relevant context; and if you discover you didn't ask the right question, it's typically better to post a new question rather than invalidating existing answers.
